# Opencv slow code: Is something wrong?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

here is a function where I try to improve the image colors. It works but it is really slow...Maybe someone has a better idea?

```
static Mat correctColor(Mat AImage) {
    Mat copyImage;
    AImage.copyTo(copyImage);
    Mat imgLab;
    cvtColor(copyImage, imgLab, CV_BGR2Lab);


    for (int y = 0; y < imgLab.rows; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < imgLab.cols; x++) {
            //get pixel value                
            imgLab.ptr<uchar > (y)[x * 3] = imgLab.ptr<uchar > (y)[x * 3]*0.3;
        }
    }
    cvtColor(imgLab, copyImage, CV_Lab2BGR);

    Mat img(copyImage.rows, copyImage.cols, CV_32FC3);
    copyImage.convertTo(img, CV_32FC3, 1 / 255.);        
    blur(img, img, Size(255, 255));
    Mat img32(copyImage.rows, copyImage.cols, CV_32FC3);
    copyImage.convertTo(img32, CV_32FC3, 1 / 255.);

    img.mul(img, 2);        
    divide(img32, img, img);

    img.convertTo(copyImage, CV_8U, 255.0);

    return copyImage;
 }
```

Comment: This should be better posted to [codereview.se]

Answer (score 2):

The major problem is that you are creating several copies of the original image in memory: AImage, copyImage, imgLab, img, img32.

First optimization should be what @Eric suggested (*pass by reference*):

```
static Mat correctColor(Mat& AImage) {
```

As for the rest of your code, see if you can decrease the number of copies you work with.

OpenCV has a *GPU module* which implements several functions in the GPU, including `cv::blur()`. This implementation is based on the CUDA framework, so if your graphics card is NVIDIA you are in luck: [`gpu::blur()`](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/gpu/doc/image_filtering.html#gpu-blur).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to optimize is to start where you spend the most time. So, I strongly recommend you to profile this code to know exactly which parts of your code are the most time-consuming.

Now, some general ideas on how to improve:

- If there is any chance to get rid of the convert to Lab, do it.
- Do not use floats. There are a number of other ways to do math, without floating point. So, try first on uchars (get rid of the normalization step), then, if the approximation is too bad, convert to unsigned short, then back to uchar, when all the calculations are done.
- Try to find another operation instead of divide. It is one of the most expensive math operations you can do on a computer. Maybe you can shift bits, or find an operation with a similar result.
- Do not access elements by ptr. Search on SO for fast Mat access.
- blur on a 255x255 window is a killer. I suspect it takes 95% of your processing time. You really cannot make it smaller? or use a box filter? or not use it at all? Or look on the internet for a FFT filter implementation. It is much faster than the simple window approach used by opencv.

Comment: Why not access elements by ptr?   @vasile

Comment: accessing elements by image.ptr<uchar> is slower than raw pointer access (extract a raw pointer to the image data, and access it by pointer indexes)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should pass your argument by reference since you already create a clone in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Improve image colors?  You should try [Histogram Equalization](http://www.opencv.org.cn/opencvdoc/2.3.1/html/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html) instead.  Look for the *equalizeHist()* function.

Comment: That's not a panacea of "improvement". Improvement is not a mathematically defined term ;)

Comment: Well... you are right. :)   But equalization is very useful for these kind of tasks.

Answer (score -2):

Apart from the optimizations to the programs. You can add compiler optimization flags like `-o3` and `-NDEBUG`, while compiling.